# ggplotly deletes axis title in combination with scale_x_continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a problem with `ggplotly` command.

It erases the `xlab` or `ylab` text if I scale the axis with `scale_x_continuous`.

```
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(a=letters, b=LETTERS, x=runif(26), y=runif(26))
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(text=sprintf('letter: %s\nLetter: %s', a, b))) +
  xlab('test') + ylab('test') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-100,100,.1), minor_breaks=seq(-100,100,.05), limits=c(0,1))
g
(gg <- ggplotly(g))
```

The `g` graph is still fine with both labels on the axis but the `ggplotly` graph deletes the title if I set a `scale` to any of the axis.

This is independent of the axis. But I didn't checked other `scales` so far.

Any idea why this happens and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure that it is intended but if you use `scale_...` function then you have to provide axis title inside `scale_...` because title set inside `labs()` or `xlab()`/`ylab()` is ignored.

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
      geom_point(aes(text=sprintf('letter: %s\nLetter: %s', a, b))) +
      ylab('test') +
      scale_x_continuous("test",breaks=seq(-100,100,.1), 
                      minor_breaks=seq(-100,100,.05), limits=c(0,1))
g
(gg <- ggplotly(g))
```